# How to append a row to a dataframe based on a condition following to the new row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Working with the following dataframe:

```
    name abbreviation     X     Y  Quantity Max Quantity
0    A-x            A  15.6  19.4         1            2
1   A-y2            A  15.6  19.4         2            2
2    B-a            B  15.0  25.0         1            2
3    B-d            B  15.0  25.0         2            2
4   C-x1            C  15.0  10.0         1            3
5   C-c4            C  15.0  10.0         2            3
6    C-5            C  15.0  10.0         3            3
7    E-v            E  83.4  16.5         1            4
8    E-2            E  83.4  16.5         2            4
9   E-v2            E  83.4  16.5         3            4
10   E-1            E  83.4  16.5         4            4 
11  F-ab            F  19.1  98.4         1            2
12  F-nb            F  19.1  98.4         2            2
13  G-ku            G  78.0  17.0         1            1
```

Depending on the x and y coordinates the quantity of same coordinate pairs is counted (5th column) and the maximum quantity of each pair is in the 6th column.

Now I want to generate a new row in front of every coordinate pair before it gets counted again, containing the abbreviation as the name, the same x and y values as the following rows and a quantity of 0.

```
    name site_abbreviation  POS_X  POS_Y  Quantity  Max Quantity
0      A                 A   15.6   19.4         0             2
1    A-x                 A   15.6   19.4         1             2
2   A-y2                 A   15.6   19.4         2             2
3      B                 B   15.0   25.0         0             2
4    B-a                 B   15.0   25.0         1             2
5    B-d                 B   15.0   25.0         2             2
6      C                 C   15.0   10.0         0             3
7   C-x1                 C   15.0   10.0         1             3
8   C-c4                 C   15.0   10.0         2             3
9    C-5                 C   15.0   10.0         3             3
10     E                 E   83.4   16.5         0             4
11   E-v                 E   83.4   16.5         1             4
12   E-2                 E   83.4   16.5         2             4
13  E-v2                 E   83.4   16.5         3             4
14   E-1                 E   83.4   16.5         4             4
15     F                 F   19.1   98.4         0             2
16  F-ab                 F   19.1   98.4         1             2
17  F-nb                 F   19.1   98.4         2             2
18     G                 G   78.0   17.0         0             1
19  G-ku                 G   78.0   17.0         1             1
```

This is how it should look like in the end.

Problem is to add the new row before the ones which it is conditioned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's groupby `abbreviation` and prepend a row before each group with `Quantity` column as 0 and `name` column as the value of `abbreviation` column

```py
out = (df.groupby(['abbreviation'], as_index=False)
       .apply(lambda g: pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([dict(g.iloc[0].to_dict(),
                                                      **{'Quantity': 0, 'name': g.name})]),
                                   g]))
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
print(out)

    name abbreviation     X     Y  Quantity  Max Quantity
0      A            A  15.6  19.4         0             2
1    A-x            A  15.6  19.4         1             2
2   A-y2            A  15.6  19.4         2             2
3      B            B  15.0  25.0         0             2
4    B-a            B  15.0  25.0         1             2
5    B-d            B  15.0  25.0         2             2
6      C            C  15.0  10.0         0             3
7   C-x1            C  15.0  10.0         1             3
8   C-c4            C  15.0  10.0         2             3
9    C-5            C  15.0  10.0         3             3
10     E            E  83.4  16.5         0             4
11   E-v            E  83.4  16.5         1             4
12   E-2            E  83.4  16.5         2             4
13  E-v2            E  83.4  16.5         3             4
14   E-1            E  83.4  16.5         4             4
15     F            F  19.1  98.4         0             2
16  F-ab            F  19.1  98.4         1             2
17  F-nb            F  19.1  98.4         2             2
18     G            G  78.0  17.0         0             1
19  G-ku            G  78.0  17.0         1             1
```